# What happens when we use delete on a pointer to an object not allocated with new operator?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator

The below code compiles fine but does not execute

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *a;
    int b = 5;
    a = &b;
    cout << *a << endl;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

```
int main()
{
    int *a = 0;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. Why is that so?

Comment: I read the question and the code was completely different. I was meaning if the OP did try to understand why the code compiles but does not execute. Of course I did not mean "Trying" as "repeatedly push the execute button on same code and see if it goes once".

Answer (score 7):

After your editing, you only have one case of undefined behaviour: 
`delete`ing memory you did not aquire by `new`.

`delete` on a NULL-pointer is guaranteed to do no harm.
But `delete` on memory you did not allocate or deleted before is undefined. The implementations I know exit your program with some sort of access violation.

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined Behaviour" means that there is no guaranteed post-condition for what you did.

People will often say that the "compiler" chooses what happens. In reality, the compiler will compile it, and the heap manager decides at runtime how it handles the situation where you call an invalid delete call.

Although the case here looks trivial to catch at compiler level, there are many cases where it is simply beyond the scope of the compiler to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It causes **undefined behavior**

1. You are using unallocated memory to store data
2. You are deleting memory that was not allocated

Both of these factors most probably cause a crash with "access violation".

But, as behavior is undefined, application can work.

Answer (score 0):

You have three cases of undefined behavior: The first is with your dereferencing and assigning using the uninitialized pointer `a`, the second is the dereferencing when printing `a`, and the last is when deleting `a`.

Comment: OP updated question removing two cases of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to write in a memory location not allocated by you.

*a = 5;

and then trying to delete a memory not allocated by you

delete a;

it has undefined behavior.

Comment: OP is asking about `delete a`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling *delete* on a pointer that has not been allocated with *new* or a *null pointer* is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) the draft C++ standard section `5.3.5` *Delete* paragraph *2* says(*emphasis mine*):

> [...]In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.

as with all *undefined behavior* anything is possible, the program could even seem to work fine but results are unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete the stack memory. In stack memory will be contagious if you tried to delete it undefined behavior will occur.

For heap memory allocation will not be contagious.